# I need to be able to store sound files for my application on sdcard

Tags: android, audio, sd-card

I've read a lot of topics but none seem to cover what I need.

I basically have a load of sound files and I want to be able to play them in the application from the sdcard.

I also want to be able to install them there in the first place when the application is installed.

I am using Eclipse with the android SDK and currently my Target project is v1.6

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need?

Comment: I am writing a soundboard application and I want to store the sound clips on the SDcard as if there are lots of them the internal phone memory will fill up, I'll also want to store text files which I will edit for settings.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I found the answer!

First we need to get the external Storage Directory to a variable called baseDir.

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then Create the directory mysounds on the SDcard

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mysounds");
boolean success = false;
if(!folder.exists())
{
    success = folder.mkdir();     
}         
if (!success) 
{ 
    // Do something on success
}
else 
{
    // Do something else on failure 
}
```

Then This following bit of code will copy all the files with sound at the beginning of the name from the assets directory to the mysounds directory you have already created.

```
try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        String[] list = am.list("");
        for (String s:list) {
            if (s.startsWith("sound")) {
                Log.d("Notice", "Copying asset file " + s);
                InputStream inStream = am.open(s);
                int size = inStream.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                inStream.read(buffer);
                inStream.close();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(baseDir + "/mysounds/" + s);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
            }
      }
 }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: You might also want to considering downloading the sound files from a website to the scard, to avoid having them inflate the .apk size.